# manifest.json file has stopped being detected in Blazor server application

Tags: progressive-web-apps, blazor

I am develping a Blazor App - in the initial stages I was able to install it as a PWA from on https://localhost:5001

Now however, the manifest.json is no longer found, and in Chrome developer tools it is detected as type 'document', rather than type 'manifest', as with other applications:

[manifest.json in chrome developer tools, network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKny7.png)

I've read the related questions on here, and I can't figure out what's wrong.

I know the manifest.json file itself is fine, because if I use it in a new Blazor project it works fine.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: If you examine the response for that request - does it contain the manifest? Have you tried clearing all cached data (from the dev tools - application - clear storage) and reloading?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply @MisterMagoo. I have answered my own question below

Comment: A server side blazor app can never be a PWA! it cannot work offline, it needs a real-time connection to the server

Comment: I'm afraid I'm going to have to respectfully disagree with your definition of a PWA @rdmptn - my application is now 'installable' (my main objective was to allow mobile users to 'add to homescreen') and locally cached content is served to the user in the event that no internet connection is available.

Answer (score 1):

I was tearing my hair out over this for an entire day, and it was a stupid mistake (as I knew it would be).

It turns out I had inadvertently put this line:

`@(Html.AntiForgeryToken())`

**Above** the `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration in my _Host.cshtml file (hidden among  @page,@namespace, @addTagHelper).

Once this was removed it started working fine again.